# Inheritance contract use the same constructor from abstract contract without the need to define again

Tags: solidity

I have 1 abstract contract and 2 contracts inherit it, they use the same constructor but I have to defined it again though I don't want to do it. I want to generate two inherited contracts inside a factory but I met problem with constructor.
This is the example code:

```
abstract contract AbstractContract is Time {
    constructor(uint256 valueA, uint256 valueB, uint256 valueC) Time(valueA) {}
}

contract A is AbstractContract {
    constructor(uint256 valueA, uint256 valueB, uint256 valueC) 
      public
      AbstractContract(valueA, valueB, valueC) {}
}

contract B is AbstractContract {
}

contract Factory {

   function createA(uint256 valueA, uint256 valueB, uint256 valueC) {
     A a = new A(valueA, valueB, valueC)    // Success
   }

   function createB(uint256 valueA, uint256 valueB, uint256 valueC) {
     B b = new B(valueA, valueB, valueC)    // Error: 3 arguments given but expected 0
   }
}
```

I don't want my contract look like the A contract, but if I do it like the B contract, I can not pass my args into new function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since contract B has no constructors defined, which means by default the constructor takes 0 arguments, but you're trying to pass three arguments to the constructor of B, you cannot define as such. If you don't define the number of arguments the constructor of contract B takes, the compiler wouldn't know how many arguments to expect, as you could pass in an arbitrary number of arguments.